# Do we say "to sing the toddler to pee / poo" or do we have similar common terms in English?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

This is common in Asia, but I am not sure if it is in Western country.

That is some parents in Asia don't want to put diapers on their toddlers. Instead, they often find a suitable time to take their toddlers to the bathroom & sing or say "/ʃ/" sound to help them to pee or poo.

In the dictionary,

**[sing](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sing_2)**

```
[intransitive, transitive] to make musical sounds with your voice in the form of a song or tune
She usually sings in the shower.
I just can't sing in tune!
He was dancing around and singing at the top of his voice(= very loudly).
sing to somebody He was singing softly to the baby.
sing something to somebody Will you sing a song to us?
We all sang ‘Happy Birthday’ to her.
sing somebody something Will you sing us a song?
sing something Now I'd like to sing a song by the Beatles.
sing somebody to sleep She sang the baby to sleep (= sang until the baby went to sleep).
```

In the dictionary, people say "**sing somebody to sleep**", but sometimes we don't sing them to pee / poo, we may say "**/ʃ/**" sound as a good way to help them to pee / poo

Do we say "**to sing the toddler to pee / poo**" or do we have similar common terms in English?

Answer (score 3):

No, Tom. One doesn't do that here. I'm keen to try it though and am already compiling a list of songs I think might do the trick.